# Download a Google Docs Spreadsheet as HTML

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Im using the Google Drive api with php to do all sorts of wonderful things but getting stuck with downloading a Spreadsheet in HTML format. I can use the getExportLinks() method to download it in its various formats, but all i want is the text from the sheet and not a formatted file in docx or ods.

This was possible with the google docs api by using the /feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&key=ID url. But currently being redirected when I use it.

Is it possible to download a spreadsheet as html using the drive api?

Comment: have you found any solution to this? spreadsheet can be export to xlsx, ods and pdf, but not HTML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the exportformat in the exportLink to html.

Answer (score 3):

@Andre J's answer works, the code:

```
Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
File file = driveService.files().get(____documentKey____).execute();
String downloadUrl = file.getExportLinks().get("application/pdf");
downloadUrl = downloadUrl.replaceFirst("exportFormat=pdf", "exportFormat=html");
HttpResponse resp = driveService.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(downloadUrl))
    .execute();

System.out.println("downloadUrl: " + downloadUrl);
InputStream fileContent = resp.getContent();
String htmlContent = new Scanner(fileContent).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

System.out.println("htmlContent: " + htmlContent);
```