# Get FontStyle information from Google spreadsheet into appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Google spreadsheets contain FontStyle information, such as bold, red,  etc. 
I want to read the FontStyle  from the spreadsheet.

Is GAS the only way to read FontStyle info from a google spreadsheet? Are there any other options?

I am using appengine and Gdata/Spreadsheet API with OAuth. This is reading Cell Data from the google spreadsheet.

Gdata & Google Spreadsheets API 3.0:
I have searched Gdata & Google Spreadsheets API, as far as I can tell, these only read cell data. There is a GData feature request to read FontStyle info [here](http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1263) :

Avoid Google Apps Script:
I want to avoid using google apps script. I know GAS can read FontStyle info. But GAS is complex/scary for a non programmer to setup and so I want to avoid GAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to work around this would be to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) instead and [download the spreadsheet in HTML format](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents). Then you can parse the HTML to determine the cell fonts and colors.

Comment: Had not thought of doing a download. I will look into it. This says download as HTML is possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082918/download-a-google-docs-spreadsheet-as-html. Will check if it exports style info.

Comment: Google example of how to download a file from google drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get