# how to download a spreadsheet as html using drive api?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I can develop downloading a spreadsheet file as html function when I use documents list api, but I can't download spreadsheet as html using drive api.

I've found this problem after migrating from docs list api to drive api.

Is there any way to downloading a spreadsheet as html using drive api?

Please advise,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Old style spreadsheet (max 400,000 cells) this works:

[Download a Google Docs Spreadsheet as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082918/download-a-google-docs-spreadsheet-as-html?rq=1)

With new style spreadsheet, I have not tested, but I assume you can use the above method to download it as a zip. So if you open your spreadsheet, select download as html, it will give you the link to the zip. Use this link as described in "Download a Google Docs Spreadsheet as HTML". So, I have not tested this, but it looks like everything is the same, so it might work.