# How to export a Google Spreadsheet as EXCEL?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to export the content in a Google Spreadsheet as a .xlsx file. What should I do?

Is it possible to do with command-line? (like nodejs)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

### Download google spreadsheet

excel/pdf/HTML/csv etc

Use "Google drive API" - code:
[Download a Google Docs Spreadsheet as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082918/download-a-google-docs-spreadsheet-as-html/14887153#14887153)

You can download as anything that is offered by the Spreadsheet menu.
I suspect OAuth2 is required.